# HPLaserjet 1000 stopped working with Rel. 14

Tags: drivers, printing, hplip

HP Laserjet 1000 stopped working when I upgraded to Rel. 14.  Have tried similar problem fixes found on Ubuntu sites, but none of the suggestions worked.  Can anyone point me to a similar problem that got answered?  I think I don't know how to ask the right question.  Have a small biz and really need to get the printer going.  Thanks.   Finlander42

Comment: Can your confirm Ubuntu **14.04 LTS** or **14.10**?

Comment: According to http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_1000.html the 1000 model is supported by HPLIP under **14.04** and **14.10**.